# Show $\phi$ has a unique fixed point

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Let $\phi : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function of classe $\mathscr{C}^{1}$ such that
$$
\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}}{\text{sup}}\left|\phi'\left(x\right)\right|<1
$$

I need to show it exists a unique fixed point $\phi\left(x^{\ast}\right) = x^{\ast}$. The original exercise suggests to assess the sign of $x - \phi\left(x\right)$ for a sufficiently large $\left|x\right|$.

My try is to work on $\left[a;+\infty\right[$ with $a>0$ use mean value inequality :
$$
\left|\phi\left(x\right) - \phi\left(a\right) \right|<\left|x-a\right|
$$
using the hypothesis on $\phi'$. However I can't see how I can use this to solve the question. Any hint ?

Comment: See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: As stated, this isn't true. Consider $\phi(x)=x+\frac{1}{1+e^x}$. You either need to be working on a bounded interval (in which case you can use the mean value inequality and follow the Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem) or you need $\mid\phi'(x)\mid<c$ for some constant $c\<1$, in which case you can use that $x-\phi(x)$ is strictly increasing and cannot have asymptotes. Unless when you say max, that maximum is actually achieved. I assumed that you meant sup, but if you mean max, then take $c$ to be that maximum

Comment: @Aidan You are wrong. If $c$ is the maximum in the statement then $c <1$ and $|\phi'(x)|\leq c$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Aidan Yeah i meant sup

Answer (score 1):

Let $c:=\max_{\mathbb R}|\varphi '|$.

**For the unicity**

Let $x,y\in \mathbb R$ being two fixed point of $\varphi $. As you said, using mean value theorem, $$|x-y|=|\varphi (x)-\varphi (y)|\leq c|x-y|<|x-y|,$$
which is a contradiction.

**For existence (Hint)**

Define $x_0=0$ and $x_{n+1}=\varphi (x_n)$. Show that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Let $x$ be its limit. Using continuity of $\varphi $, it will be a fix point of $\varphi $.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) ?

Here, by hypothesis and mean value inequality, for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|<\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}|\phi'(t)||x-y|,$$
so that $\phi$ is a contraction mapping since $\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}|\phi'(t)|<1$.